# There was an error running the selected code generator: while creating a scaffolded item

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2019

Iam trying to add a **Scaffolded item** but i got an error.
It took me alot of time searching for this error, but actually i couldn't find a way out.
I tried deleting Cache, rebuild project but none of these worked.

The error is :
**There was an error running the selected code generator: Method 'getInfo' in type 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore.Infraestructure.MySQLOptionsExtension' from assembly 'MySql.Data.EntityFrameworkCore, Version =8.0.19.0, Culture=neutral doesn't have an implementation .**

[**Here is the controller item i tried to add ''Click Here''**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJyzn.png)

[**Project Packages ''Click Here''**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcfoy.png)

After a long search i found that these packages are compatible with each other.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to use the .NET 4.6 Entity Framework alongside the .NET Core Entity Framework, wich might be causing some problems.
Have you tried to remove the package "Entity Framework (6.4.0)" from your solution to see if it works?

Comment: No, actually i didn't try this. But, finally after searching here and there i knew that there is a problem in the compatibility of the packages with each other. So, i deleted all the MySql packages and i used Pomelo instead and it works all well.